# sort table dynamically using cookies

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I´m trying to sort a table dinamically by using javaScript (jquery) / PHP and coockies.

mi code is this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
            var exdate=new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
                x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
                x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                if (x==c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("a").toggle(function(){
                setCookie("orden","ASC",100);
            }, function() {
                setCookie("orden","DESC",100);
            });

            $("a").click(function(){
                setCookie("campo",$(this).html(),100);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ordenaTabla.php",
                    //data: ,
                    success:function(data) {
                        //alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabla">
        <table border="1" align="center" width="300">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="#">ID</a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#">nombre</a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#">edad</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                include_once ("mySqlConexion.inc.php");

                $tabla    = "tablaPruebas";

                if(isset($_COOKIE["consulta"])){
                    $consulta = $_COOKIE["consulta"];
                    $consulta = str_replace("+", " ", $consulta);
                }
                else{
                    $consulta = "SELECT * from ".$tabla;
                }

                echo $consulta;
                echo print_r($_COOKIE);

                //En la variable resultado se mete el resultado de la ejecución de la consulta que se ejecuta gracias a la funcion mysql_query
                $resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $link);

                while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$fila["ID"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$fila["nombre"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$fila["edad"]."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                };
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the code I use on the php file i call using AJAX is this:

```
$tabla    = "tablaPruebas";
$consulta = "SELECT+*+FROM+".$tabla."+ORDER+BY+".$_COOKIE["campo"]."+".$_COOKIE["orden"];

//I create this cookie by using the value of the other 2 cookies I already have
     $_COOKIE["consulta"] = $consulta;
```

I was wondering if you could tell me why it does not work :(

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you need to identify what does work and what part of code is causing problems. Simply dumping a bunch of code into a post and saying "it doesn't work" doesn't tell anyone much. Also helps to identify steps you have tried to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored on the clients computer.

It is a bad idea to store an sql query on the clients computer, since the client can execute random sql on your database by editing the cookie, like dropping all tables.

You would instead use a shorthand for the required ordering and set the order by clause in a switch control statement.

Also, I would not use a cookie at all, but simply hand over the required ordering in a parameter to the ajax POST.

Here are some snippets how it could look:

```
//javascript
$("a").click(function(){
            var campo= "name asc";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ordenaTabla.php",
                data: {campo: campo},
                success:function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                }
            });

});

//PHP
switch($_POST['campo']){
     case "name asc": $orderby= "ORDER BY name ASC"; break;
     default: $orderby= "";
}
```